# plotly polarplot - moving position of radialaxis labels

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plotly for polar plots with pretty standard settings for radial and angular axis, but  instead of plotting the ticklabels of the radialaxis onto the 270 degree axis, I would like to plot them onto the 180 degree axis. How can I do that?

Here some snippets of my code:

```
fig.update_layout(
    title="",
    font_size=25,
    showlegend=False,
    polar=dict(
        bgcolor="white",
        angularaxis=dict(
            rotation=90,  # Rotate 90 degrees to shift 0 degrees to the top
            direction="counterclockwise",  # Rotate in the clockwise direction
            linewidth=4,
            showline=False,
            linecolor='black',
            gridcolor="black",
            tickmode="array",
            tickvals=[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315],
            ticktext=["0°", "45°","90°", "135°","180°","225°", "270°","315°"],
           
        ),
        radialaxis=dict(
        side="counterclockwise",
        showline=False,
        linewidth=4,
        range=[0, 20],
        gridcolor="black",
        gridwidth=3,
        tickvals=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20],  # Adjust the tick values based on your data
        ticktext=['0', '5', '10', '15', '20'],  # Use empty strings to hide the default tick labels
        linecolor='black'
        )
    ),
    paper_bgcolor = "white"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by setting the [radialaxis angle](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/polar/#layout-polar-radialaxis-angle) :

> Sets the angle (in degrees) from which the radial axis is drawn.

```py
    radialaxis=dict(
        angle=-90,
        tickangle=-90, # for the axis ticks to stay horizontal 
        ...
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! Right now, however, the radial axis and the angular axis tick labels overlap. Is there a way to more the angular axis tick labels farther out? I know there is a parameter for that in matplotlib (called "pad"), but did not find anything like this in plotly

Comment: I'm not sure there is a parameter for that purpose. However, if you make the grid/axes lines lighter (in both color and thickness compared to the tick labels) the overlapping wouldn't be an issue, cf. [examples](https://plotly.com/python/polar-chart/#basic-polar-chart), but it's subjective.